# Solving this augmented matrix for a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I attempted to do the following exercise with no luck. I was sure of the answer, but apparently not.. somehow...

*The given matrix is the augmented matrix for a linear system in the variables $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$. Solve the system. (If there is no solution, enter **NO SOLUTION**.)*

|$1 \ \ \ \ \ \ 0  \ \ \ \ \ \ 5 \ \ \ | \ \ \ 0$|
|$0 \ \ \ \ \ \ 1  \ -1 \ \ \ | \ \ \ 0$|
|$0 \ \ \ \ \ \ 0  \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ | \ \ \ 0$|

*What is $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = $*

---

Here's what I tried.
From the first equation, I moved the $5$ to the right side then end up with $x_1=-5$.
For the second equation, I moved the $-1$ to the right side to obtain $x_2=1$.
Finally, the third equation yields $0=0$ which can be interpreted as $t$.
My final answer was $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (-5, 1, t)$, but supposedly it's wrong.   Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That should have been $x_1 = -5 x_3$, so you have a free variable. Do same for second row, so we wave $x_2 = x_3$. Now we know that $x_3$ is a free variable.

Comment: oh wow, I think you made me realize what I did wrong. I completely forgot about the $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$. So the final answer become $(-5s, s, s)$. Thanks @Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the augmented matrix representation of a system of linear equations, each line represents an equation where whatever lies on the right of the vertical bar is the constant term of the equation. In your case, there are three variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and three equations

$$ 1 \cdot x_1 + 0 \cdot x_2 + 5 \cdot x_3 = x_1 + 5x_3 = 0, \\
   0 \cdot x_1 + 1 \cdot x_2 - 1 \cdot x_3 = x_2 - x_3 = 0, \\
   0 \cdot x_1 + 0 \cdot x_2 + 0 \cdot x_3 = 0.
$$

Thus, we obtain $x_2 = x_3$ and $x_1 = -5x_3$ where $x_3$ is a free variable so the general solution for the system of equations is of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (-5t, t, t)$.

Answer (score 1):

That augmented matrix actually refers to the system
$$
1x_1+0x_2+5x_3=0\\
0x_1+1x_2-1x_3=0\\
0x_1+0x_2+0x_3=0\\
$$
So following your foot-steps we get $x_1=-5x_3,x_2=x_3$. So the solutions are of the form $(-5,1,1)x_3.$